# Issue with creating chrome instance with seleno

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am upgrading my .net code to the latest version of selenium. I get the following error when Seleno host creates an instance of `chromeAutofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException`:

> An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> Method not found: 'OpenQA.Selenium.ITimeouts OpenQA.Selenium.ITimeouts.ImplicitlyWait(System.TimeSpan)

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Seleno does not work with the latest version of selenium. The best way would be to use the inbuilt selenium constructs.